# Get the total number of samples in opus file (libogg and libopus)

Tags: ogg, opus

Is there a way to get the total number of pcm samples inside an ogg file containing opus audio using libogg and libopus?

Thanks,

Comment: Seems that there is no straight forward way to grab the total number of samples within an `opus` audio file. I ended up reading the entire file for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a similar modification to opus-tools' `opusinfo` command:

1. issue: [Show total samples used to calculate duration in opusinfo](https://github.com/xiph/opus-tools/issues/40)
2. commit: [opusinfo: Add total playback samples to output](https://github.com/xiph/opus-tools/pull/41/commits/f20161d77f932f81a3dff56644bc5cc42d29959e)